# How to get default values of a method (jQuery Plugin)

Tags: jquery, plugins, default

```
$.fn.myFunction = function(options) {
    var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.myFunction.defaults, options);        
    $.fn.myFunction.defaults = {
        var1: 123,
        var2: 987
    }
}
```

I need get var1 (= 123) outside the myFunction... how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to be able to access that value from anywhere?

```
console.log($.fn.myFunction.defaults.var1) // 123
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case,

```
var default1 = $.fn.myFunction.defaults.va1;
```

but there is no general (plugin-agnostic) way to do this.